# How to switch the window buttons to the left in Cinnamon?

Tags: window-buttons, cinnamon

I tried Ubuntu Tweak and dconf-editor but nothing seemed to help. Perhaps if there is an extension for the same, please share if you happen to know this or any other workaround.

[image]

Comment: I notice that this post is tagged "cinnamon." I am not familiar with this desktop environment. I suggest that having the open/close/maximize buttons on the left is part of the cinnamon way of doing things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am guessing it has retained the same gconf settings as gnome-shell since it is just a fork of gnome-shell.

So, you can change the window control buttons layout using [gconf-editor](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gconf-editor) [image: Install gconf-editor].

After installing it, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gconf-editor`.

Then, move to `Desktop -> gnome -> shell -> windows`, and double click on the entry and enter these for `button_layout`: `close,minimize,maximize:`.

All that matters is the position of the `:`.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, on Linux Mint 13, BUT: I had to restart cinnamon. Run "sudo killall cinnamon && cinnamon --replace &" to restart cinnamon

Comment: I can't find a 'Shell' under 'Gnome' anymore.

Comment: A solution that doesn't include commands is preferable (see Maimon Mons answer)

Answer (score 28):

Cinnamon Settings -> Window -> Left Sided Title Bar buttons.
[image: Titlebar section of cinnamon's window settings]
You might have to restart cinnamon to see the changes;
here are some ways to do that:

- Right click the panel -> Troubleshoot -> Restart Cinnamon
- Open a terminal and type `cinnamon --replace &`

(No need for gconf-editor!!!)

Answer (score 8):

## UPDATE FOR 12.10

The other answers didn't work for me in 12.10, so here is how I did it.

There are actually two ways of doing this.

1. Open "Cinnamon Settings" and click 'Windows'.  Here you can change the buttons in the title bar and which side they are on.

[image]

2. You can also use `dconf-editor`.  First install `dconf` using

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```

Open `dconf-editor` and navigate to:

```
org --> cinnamon --> overrides
```

Rearrange the value of `button-layout` from:

```
:minimize,maximize,close
```

to

```
close,minimize,maximize:
```

[image]

This will move the title buttons from the right side to the left in Cinnamon 1.6.7 and Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Thanks, using dconf-editor, I was able to add a 'stick' button so I could toggle sticky windows (always on visible workspace).  Currently not implemented in Cinnamon Settings.

Answer (score 0):

It's in each theme itself. For instance go to usr/themes/Ambiance open the document Ambiance as administrator. At the bottom of the document you'll see this 
ButtonLayout=close,minimize,maximize:

move the colon to the front of close like this 
ButtonLayout=:close,minimize,maximize

Comment: Its already set to :close,minimize,maximize but still it is showing on the right hand site.

Answer (score 0):

this one still works.

press alt+f2, go to Apps-metacity-general, edit the "button layout" into this **"close,minimize,maximize:"**

it will change right away

Answer (score 0):

In dconfig-editor go to `/desktop/cinnamon/windows` and alter `button_layout.`